# php sqlsrv_query stored procedure with naming parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

Im using php 5.4 with sqlsrv extension and I'm trying to call this sample stored procedure (NorthWind database):

```
create  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCategories] 
@CategoryID int = null
AS
SELECT * from dbo.Categories where CategoryID= IsNull(@CategoryID,CategoryID)
```

And I'm using this sqlsrv_query syntax:

```
$sql = "{ call dbo.GetCategories (?)}";
$catID=2;
$params = array($catID);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql,$params);
```

I want to specify parameter name and value in $params, just like this:

```
$sql = "dbo.GetCategories";
$catID=2;
$params = array("@CategoryID"=>$catID);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql,$params);
```

It return this error: String keys are not allowed in parameters arrays.

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlsrv:server= ...');
$sql = "{CALL dbo.GetCategories (@CategoryID=:CategoryID)}";
$stmt = $dbh ->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam('CategoryID', $catID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();

$results = array();
do {
    $results []= $stmt->fetchAll();
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());

echo '<pre>';


echo($results[0][0]['CategoryID'] . ', '.
         $results[0][0]['CategoryName'] . ', '.
         $results[0][0]['Description']);
echo '</pre>';

$stmt->closeCursor();
unset($stmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use associative arrays for binding values to SQL parameters. The elements in the array must be in the same order as the parameters.